# OKTA IDP initiated Single logout is not performed

Tags: spring-security, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, spring-saml, okta

I have successfully integrated my app with OKTA via Spring Security SAML library. The SSO works perfectly fine either from IdP, or from SP side, but the SLO process works only if I perform global logout via {context}/saml/logout call and send LogoutRequest to OKTA. In this case OKTA responds with an LogoutResponse, all my handlers do their job and I am also signed out from OKTA.

I was wondering what is the default behavior of OKTA if I logout from my OKTA account? Should OKTA send LogoutRequest to the configured SLO endpoint on SP side and I will be logged out by my Logout handlers?

Comment: Okta only support SP initiated single logout that you have already implemented and working for you, where you logout from app and it also logs you out from Okta. IDP initiated logout where you will logout from Okta and gets logged out from app too, is not supported.

Comment: Thank you @SohaibAjmal !